# A logical error occured in knapsack memoization recurrsion problem and I can't figure out

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, knapsack-problem

Basically, we need to pick the best according to the profits and capacity.

Here are the inputs and outputs

```py
test0 = {
    'input': {
        'capacity': 165,
        'weights': [23, 31, 29, 44, 53, 38, 63, 85, 89, 82],
        'profits': [92, 57, 49, 68, 60, 43, 67, 84, 87, 72]
    },
    'output': 309
}
```

I tried to solve it using normal recursion and it worked fine
RECURSION

```py
def lc_rec(weights, profits, capacity, idx=0):
    if idx == len(weights):
        return 0
    elif weights[idx] > capacity:
        return lc_rec(weights, profits, capacity, idx+1)
    else:
        option1 = lc_rec(weights, profits, capacity, idx+1)
        option2 = profits[idx] + lc_rec(weights, profits, capacity - weights[idx], idx+1)
        return max(option1, option2)
```

I tried memoized recursion and some logical error occured and the outputs are not as expected
MEMOIZED RECURSION

```py
def lc_memo(weights, profits, capacity):
    memo ={}
    def mei(capacity, idx=0):
        key = (capacity, idx)
        if key in memo:
            return memo[key]
        elif weights[idx] > capacity:
            memo[key] = 0
            idx += 1
        else:
            option1 = mei(capacity, idx+1)
            option2 = profits[idx] + mei(capacity - weights[idx], idx+1)
            memo[key] = max(option1, option2)
            return memo[key]
    return mei(0,0)
```

Comment: In function `mei`, there is no return in your `elif` branch so in that case `None` is returned. Also please avoid vague statements such as *some logical error occured and the outputs are not as expected*.  This does not say much. If an exception is raised then update your post with the traceback.  If the output is not correct, post the excepted output and the current output for comparison.